# How to replace all matches with an incrementing number in BASH?

Tags: bash, sed

I have a text file like this:

```
AAAAAA this is some content.
This is AAAAAA some more content AAAAAA. AAAAAA
This is yet AAAAAA some more [AAAAAA] content.
```

I need to replace all occurrence of `AAAAAA` with an incremented number, e.g., the output would look like this:

```
1 this is some content.
This is 2 some more content 3. 4
This is yet 5 some more [6] content.
```

How can I replace all of the matches with an incrementing number?

Comment: Somebody asked the same problem in the ruby tag yesterday.  Just wondering if you guys are in the same class.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it:

```
$ awk '{for(x=1;x<=NF;x++)if($x~/AAAAAA/){sub(/AAAAAA/,++i)}}1' file
1 this is some content.
This is 2 some more content 3. 4
This is yet 5 some more [6] content.
```

Comment: I wouldn't do that second one - consider what it would do if an input line contained `A set of AAAAAA reps`.

Comment: Thanks @EdMorton. True, the original question I guess was later modified to show just set of 6 A's. Have removed the second suggestion.

Answer (score 5):

A perl solution:

```
perl -pe 'BEGIN{$A=1;} s/AAAAAA/$A++/ge' test.dat
```

Comment: Interesting (to me anyway!) semantic difference between awk and perl here - in perl `A` gets incremented once per substitution but in awk (`awk -vRS='^$' 'BEGIN{A=1} gsub(/AAAAAA/,A++)'`) A is incremented just once, after the substitutions.

Comment: @EdMorton: Perl can swing both ways. The `e` flag means "evaluate the replacement each time." If I'd written `s/AAAAAA/{$A++}/g`, I would have gotten a different result. (In Python, you can write `re.sub("A{6}",string,callable)` but if you want the callable to do something interesting, you probably need to define it; it's not a convenient interface for one-liners. Lua would have been another possibility -- it also allows callables as replacement, and has a more convenient syntax -- but it's not installed by default on most distros, unfortunately.

Comment: Ah perl, where even the code you think is clear turns out to have a twist :-). The closer awk equivalent to the original statement then would be `awk -vRS='^$' '{while(sub(/AAAAAA/,++A));}1' file`. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r ':a;/AAAAAA/{x;:b;s/9(_*)$/_\1/;tb;s/^(_*)$/0\1/;s/$/:0123456789/;s/([^_])(_*):.*\1(.).*/\3\2/;s/_/0/g;x;G;s/AAAAAA(.*)\n(.*)/\2\1/;ta}' file
```

This is a toy example, perl or awk would be a better fit for a solution.

The solution only acts on lines which contain the required string (`AAAAAA`).

The hold buffer is used as a place to keep the incremented integer.

In overview: when a required string is encountered, the integer in the hold space is incremented, appended to the current line, swapped for the required string and the process is then repeated until all occurences of the string are accounted for.

Incrementing an integer simply swaps the last digit (other than trailing 9's) for the next integer in sequence i.e. 0 to 1, 1 to 2 ... 8 to 9. Where trailing 9's occur, each trailing 9 is replaced by a non-integer character e.g '_'. If the number being incremented consists entirely of trailing 9's a `0` is added to the front of the number so that it can be incremented to `1`. Following the increment operation, the trailing 9's (now `_`'s) are replaced by '0's.

As an example say the integer 9 is to be incremented:

`9` is replaced by `_`, a `0` is prepended (`0_`), the `0` is swapped for 1 (`1_`), the `_` is replaced by `0`. resulting in the number `10`.

See comments directed at @jaypal for further notes.

Comment: Whenever you get a chance, can you please update the answer to add some explanation. I would really like to learn the process of creating a lookup table for referencing data. (I'm guessing that number sequence is for that).

Comment: @jaypal one explanation of lookup tables in sed can be found [here](http://sed.sf.net/grabbag/tutorials/lookup_tables.txt). Incrementing a number [here](http://sed.sourceforge.net/grabbag/scripts/incr_num.sed).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this

```
#!/bin/bash
NR=1
cat filename  while read line
do
   line=$(echo $line | sed 's/AAAAA/$NR/')
   echo ${line}
   NR=$((NR + 1 ))
done
```

Comment: That only replaces one instance of the pattern per line, and it increments the counter even for lines which have no instances of the pattern. And it doesn't expand `$NR` in the replacement because you use single-quote instead of double-quote

Answer (score 0):

Perl did the job for me

```
perl -pi -e 's/\b'DROP'\b/$&.'_'.++$A /ge' /folder/subfolder/subsubfolder/*
```

Input:

```
DROP
drop
$drop
$DROP
$DROP="DROP"
$DROP='DROP'
$DROP=$DROP
$DROP="DROP";
$DROP='DROP';
$DROP=$DROP;
$var="DROP_ACTION"
drops
DROPS
CODROP
'DROP'
"DROP"
/DROP/
```

Output:

```
DROP_1
drop
$drop
$DROP_2
$DROP_3="DROP_4"
$DROP_5='DROP_6'
$DROP_7=$DROP_8
$DROP_9="DROP_10";
$DROP_11='DROP_12';
$DROP_13=$DROP_14;
$var="DROP_ACTION"
drops
DROPS
CODROP
'DROP_15'
"DROP_16"
/DROP_17/
```