# How to replace all matches with an incrementing number with a prefix string in awk

Tags: shell, awk

I have a text file like this:

```
AAAAAA this is some content.
This is AAAAAA some more content AAAAAA. AAAAAA
This is yet AAAAAA some more [AAAAAA] content.
```

I need to replace all occurrence of AAAAAA with an incremented number, e.g., the output would look like this:

```
x1 this is some content.
This is x2 some more content x3. x4
This is yet x5 some more [x6] content.
```

How can I replace all of the matches with an incrementing number **and with a string prefix**?

my quetion is very similar to 
[How to replace all matches with an incrementing number in BASH?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23577516/how-to-replace-all-matches-with-an-incrementing-number-in-bash) however the solution given which i tried to modify, can't seem to get working.

```
awk '{for(x=1;x<=NF;x++)if($x~/AAAAAA/){sub(/AAAAAA/,"x"++i)}}1' file
```

thanks.

Comment: Try to always select any of the answer to your question as correct answer after some time of your post to make the thread complete.

Comment: The script you say you can't seem to get working produces the expected output you asked from from your posted sample input. What problem are you having with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` to save here:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/A+/){val="x"++count;sub(/A+/,val,$i)}}} 1' Input_file
```

***OR***

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/A+/){sub(/A+/,"x"++count,$i)}}} 1' Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
x1 this is some content.
This is x2 some more content x3. x4
This is yet x5 some more [x6] content.
```

Answer (score 4):

another `awk`

```
$ awk -v w='AAAAAA' '{while($0~w) sub(w,"x"++c)}1' file

x1 this is some content.
This is x2 some more content x3. x4
This is yet x5 some more [x6] content.
```

essentially an inefficient `gsub`.

this one uses record separator as the search word

```
$ awk -v RS='AAAAAA' -v ORS='' 'NR>1 && $0="x"++c $0' file

x1 this is some content.
This is x2 some more content x3. x4
This is yet x5 some more [x6] content.
```

to suppress the last one is harder, instead delayed the replacement by one and suppress the first one.

Comment: In the two examples that use the record separator for searching, how do you suppress the final x7 that is printed after the last record (the string " content." in your example)?

Comment: thanks for the comment, it didn't suppress.  I updated with the fix.

Answer (score 0):

The shortest `perl` trick:

```
perl -pe 's/\bA+\b/x.++$i/ge' file
```

The output:

```
x1 this is some content.
This is x2 some more content x3. x4
This is yet x5 some more [x6] content.
```