# Linux Replace a particular string with consecutive numbers

Tags: regex, linux, bash, awk, sed

```
CONFIG.CONFIG
create state file${number_of_edges} {
 {interval=60 
idle_interval_notification="DISABLED"}    
}
create state file${number_of_edges} {
 {interval=60 
idle_interval_notification="DISABLED"}    
}
```

I have file which has content like above. I want to replace ${number_of_edges} string with consecutive numbers like 0,1,2 and so on

```
EXPECTED OUTPUT
create state file0 {
 {interval=60 
idle_interval_notification="DISABLED"}    
}
create state file1{
 {interval=60 
idle_interval_notification="DISABLED"}    
}
create state file2 {
 {interval=60 
idle_interval_notification="DISABLED"}    
}
```

Comment: Please do add your efforts in your Question, which you have put in order to solve your own problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace all matches with an incrementing number in BASH?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23577516/how-to-replace-all-matches-with-an-incrementing-number-in-bash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `awk` script:

```
awk 'sub("\\${number_of_edges}",cnt+1, $0){cnt++}1' input.txt
```

#### Explanation:

`sub("\\${number_of_edges}",cnt+1, $0)` For each input line, substitute, ${number_of_edges} with variable (cnt + 1)

`{cnt++}` If substituted more than 0, increment variable cnt

`1` output each input line

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution.

**Command** -

```
awk -vRS=edge '{$0=n$0;ORS=RT}++n' FILE
```

Comment: IMHO,may be you can add this code as an effort in your post. Are you sure this command is giving same expected output as your requirement? When I run it,it provides different results than your sample expected ones.